# Advanced GREP / AWK - Export Characters > [X]

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, grep

I have a large log file with over 900k entries. I'd like to do a couple of things using Grep / AWK (if it is even possible):

I'd like to export a new txt file for each line entry for the symbol "~". With the conditions:

If one line/entry uses the symbol "~" more than 2 times only then should it be included in the new txt file.

Any ideas on how (or if possible) to do this using Grep / AWK?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you just want to find lines that have `~` twice anywhere in the line?  Some sample input and expected output would probably help clarify the problem

Comment: `grep '~.*~.*~' logfile > newfile`

Comment: Actually, lines that use "~" 2 times OR MORE. :) The input is a crawl log file with URLs per line. The output should be the same but should only contain the entries that contain 2 or more uses of "~".

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output. There are some things about your question that are ambigous (e.g. `I'd like to export a new txt file for each line` mean a new output file per output line or 1 new output file for all output lines?) that sample input/output will clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with grep:

```
grep -E '~.*~.*~' input > output
```

or

```
grep -E '(~.*){3}' input > output
```

Comment: Is it possible for something that doesn't require a specific number but more of a logical condition? Such as "> 2"

Comment: The second `grep` has a parameter in it (3). It means that it requires >=3 (which is equivalent to >2).

Comment: Awesome. I'll give this a try. By the way, this is my first time asking a question here and I was expecting to hear some input in a week or something. Gotta love this community. Thanks agan @redneb. I'll try this out.

Answer (score 2):

give this one-liner a try:

```
awk -F'~' 'NF>3' file > newFile
```

- `-F` defines the field delimiter. we defined `~`
- if there were at least two `~`s, the line should have at least 3 fields
- if you want the line with exact two `~`s as well, change `NF>3` into `NF>2`

Comment: Just to clarify what is "NF" in the sample you gave?

Comment: @Marc from awk man page: `The variable NF is set to the total number of fields in the input record.`

Comment: Got it! Thanks. Will give this a try as well. I appreciate the help! :)

Comment: OP wanted lines with **more** than 2 `~`s so tweak the 3 to 4.